# How to redirect user to another page from view after it was loaded is ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

For example I have some view with action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Action", "Controller")
```

`Action` action returns some view:

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    string someModelForView = "some url i need to redirect after view was fully loaded";
    return View("SomeView", someModelForView);
}
```

What I need is to redirect user to url, defined in `someModelForView` model after view was fully loaded, and all javascripts on this page were executed. This view might be empty, without any content, I just need to execute some javascript, and after that redirect user to external page. How can accomplish that?

Comment: using jQuery you can $(document).ready()

Comment: Why must it be done in javascript if there is no content? Why not just use c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the view has been rendered and the JavaScript loaded, you (the server) have already sent your response (encapsulated in the returned `ActionResult`) to the client (the browser). Thus, you cannot let ASP.NET MVC redirect you – the server has finished handling the request.

You can use JavaScript redirecting instead, though:

```
// Here goes your JavaScript code that needs to be executed
// ...

// ... and here comes the redirect:
window.location.href = "http://newurl.com";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do a redirect directly, as @achristov has suggested. But if you must return `SomeView` to execute the javascript you can use this:

```
@model string
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javescript">
            $(document).ready( function() {
                // all your javascript code...
                // ...and then:
                window.location = "@Model";
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `Model` will frequently include user data (eg, a title)

Comment: But not this model... so your rant does not apply here.